# After Response.Redirect() don't display label

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

First I have login form  (Najava.aspx) who check the status :

```
if (Session["Status"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Najava.aspx");
            Label3.Text = "You waiting activation!";
        }
```

With this I check if the user is not activated. I redirect again to the login form and I like in label to display text, but label don't display text after redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to set the text inside the `Page_Load` event of `Najava.aspx`. And if you need to display it only conditionally then you could pass a query string parameter when redirecting and then display the label only if this parameter is present:

```
if (Session["Status"].ToString() == "0")
{
    Response.Redirect("Najava.aspx?waitingactivation=true");
}
```

and then inside the `Page_Load` event of `Najava.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["waitingactivation"]))
    {
        Label3.Text = "You waiting activation!";
    }
}
```

Also you might consider using [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).